# Jongo vs (DBObject)JSON.parse

Tags: java, mongodb, jongo

I'm trying to figure out the advantage of Jongo over simply unmarshalling the json command using (DBObject)JSON.parse(...) and using the DBObject in the below fashion.

Is there a performance advantage?

```
    @Override
public List<T> getEntityList(Integer limit, String query) throws Exception {
    log.entering(DaoImpl.class.toString(), "getEntityList, with criteria of " + query);
    DBObject criteriaObject = null;
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    if (query != null)
        criteriaObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(query);

    DBCursor cursor = null;

    try {
        if (criteriaObject != null) {
            log.log(Level.FINEST, "getting the objects using a search criteria: " + criteriaObject);
            cursor = MongoDB.getInstance().getCollection(collection).find(criteriaObject);
        } else {
            log.log(Level.FINEST, "getting the objects without a criteria");
            cursor = MongoDB.getInstance().getCollection(collection).find();
        }

        ............etc, etc, etc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Jongo .3 unmarshalls Mongo query with the same `JSON.parse(query)`. The advantage is the way you get the results from the database. In your example, you have to iterate through a cursor, adapting every property and sub property by yourself.

```
DBObject dbo = JSON.parse("{age: 18}");
DBCursor results = users.find(dbo);
for (DBObject result : results) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername((String) result.get("username"));
    user.setAge((Integer) result.get("age"));
    user.setAddress(new Address(..));
}
```

With Jongo you directly manipulate objects:

```
Iterable<User> users = collection.find("{age: 18}").as(User.class);
```

Jongo's performance is nearly equal to the driver's.

Comment: I use gson to unmarshall the response, so I don't need to set every property myself. And Jongo also iterates through each result and unmarshalls it using JSON. So that's not an issue: new DomainConverter<T>(clazz).getObject(entity.toString())

Comment: You used GSON to unmarshall the DBCursor response? Can you please show a complete example of code? The Jongo team have been working hard to make that unmarshalling step as performant as the driver; have you computed the performance of your solution?

Comment: I'm not unmarshalling the cursor, rather the DBObject(s) returned by the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of few advantages to use jongo:

- Almost all queries can be templated :

  ```
  friends.find("{name:#, age:#}", "Joe", 18)
  ```
- Binded parameters can be BSON Primitives or any complex type :

  ```
  friends.find("{address: #}", new Address(..));
  ```
- Querying and unmarshalling is as fast as the driver. No Jackson process extra cost
- Use Jackson features to map you Pojo: polymorphism, JsonView...

BTW your GSON un/marshaller can be integrated into Jongo by implementing a [Mapper](http://jongo.org/#custom-mapper).

Comment: Templating does simplify some things, but I still don't see this being a good-enough reason to switch to jongo -- this can easily be achieved with string-replace. One way or another, if nobody else provides a better answer I'll accept yours.